# How to update the state in mounting in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

how to update the state after mounting or how to pass the state when moving from one page to another in react.

In My Scenario,  by clicking button `Add New`, it directs to AddNew page, in that clicking on `save` will redirect to display page, that works.
when i move to addnew page
In Display multiselect remain same(always en), how to get rendered state after redirecting

```
class Display extends React.PureComponent{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.state.language);
    const defLanguage = this.props.loginData.language; // "en"
    this.setState({ language: defLanguage.split(",") }, () =>
      this.callQueryApiForFetch("ONLOAD")
    );
  }
render(){
               <MultiSelect
                      filterOptions={formatLanguageArray(
                        languageConfig.pvalues
                      )}
                      setSelectedFieldValues={value => {
                        this.setState({ language: value }, () => {
                          this.callQueryApiForFetch("ONLOAD");
                        });
                      }}
                      id="language"
                      itemsSelected={this.state.language}
                      label="Select Language"
                    />

         <button className="page-header-btn icon_btn display-inline">
            <img
              title="edit"
              className="tableImage"
              src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/icons/ic_addstore.svg`}
            />
            {`Add New`}
          </button>

}

}


class AddNew extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
componentWillReceiveProps = () => {
     const defLanguage = this.props.location.state.language;
      this.setState({ language: defLanguage }); 
}
 render(){

           <Link
          to={{
            pathname: "/ui/product-info",
            state: {
              language: this.state.language
            }
          }}
          className="btn btn-themes btn-rounded btn-sec link-sec-btn"
        >
          Save
        </Link>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned to redirect to next page , you can also try   `this.props.history.push("/report")` here "/report" is the link you want to redirect to.
You can check React-Routing Concept (just a suggestion)

For sending props from parent component to child component 
your case :

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if(nextProps.someValue!==this.props.someValue){
        //Perform some operation
        this.setState({someState: someValue });
        this.classMethod();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice in React to separate state management from component rendering logic. The idea is that you pass fragments of a centralized state to your component hierarchy, from top to bottom, and allow them to use these data in their `render` method. In this approach you avoid keeping application state within the components.

Whenever a component needs to change the application state, it dispatches a message that is processed by a function called "reducer", and updates the state in the store. The whole concept is based on having a single source of truth for the entire application, and preventing components from manipulating the store directly.

The standard way to implement this is to use a design pattern called Redux, which is made available to React apps through the `react-redux` library.

I suggest you take a look at [this](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial) tutorial to learn how you use the React Redux library in practice.

Comment: Perhaps Redux is a little over the top in this case. You could just use , useReducer / useContext approach or as the others have said just pass a prop from parent to child .

Answer (score 0):

1.make the Display as Component and not PureComponent.

2.define a local state in Display

```
// default state..
state = {
 language: 'us',
}
```

3.console whether your'e getting language in Display's props(will mount).

//probably inside

> this.props.location.state

4.then set the state

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
 ...prevState,
 language: --value--,
})
```